# Typo3 - enable frontend users to create content

Tags: mysql, database, typo3, frontend

I got a huge problem I guess. So my situation is that I am using Typo3 and I have sr_feuser_register enabled and the extension seminars aswell. What I am trying to achieve is that frontend users are able to create seminars. It would be great if it was possible with the extension seminars. Otherwise it would be fine for me to realize it with the Typo3 Browser. The major problem is that Users should be able to create several seminars. I don't really know how to realize a 1:n connection for a frontend user and a seminar DB.

To sum it up: I want to somehow give frontend users the function to create their own seminars (realized with seminars or just in a new DB-table) in the frontend so I don't have to manually create the seminars on my own for them.

I appreciate any help as I don't really even know where to start.

Comment: Did you check extension manual ? I don't know it but in description author writes it allows to put new semnars by FE users

Comment: Ok I'm just dump. I thougt it was just possible to give users rights to edit an existing event. Now I read the whole documentation about fe editing and it should work. Thanks! And sorry for the dumb question...

Comment: If you are making your custom seminar extension then create one form like contact form, fields required information, and in backend end page tree add plugin into that page and show that page only when 'Any login'. so, in frontend after FE login your seminar form will display and after adding all info. your seminar info. will save in DB. and also save FE user uid.